# How to wake up only one using WaitForSingleObject in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, winapi

I have concerns right now

Create an event using CreateEvent.
`HANDLE g_hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);`

And about 10 Threads are created, and each thread is
Wait using `WaitForSingleObject(g_hEvent,INFINITE)`

Do this and each wait for the same Event.
In the subsequent code, when a specific situation occurs, SetEvent is activated to wake up the waiting thread.

This is where I discovered the problem of inefficiency.

In fact, you only need to wake up one thread using `SetEvent`. However, if you run the above code, all 10 threads are woken up and compete, and only the thread that wakes up first runs, and the rest go into the wait state.

Instead of using this inefficient method, I want to wake up only one thread. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Just an idea: create 10 events for each thread for waking up, then create a wakeup manager which will call set event based on what thread you want to wake up. You may wake them up in round-robin manner, for example.

Comment: If you do as you said, you will test whether the thread is valid, which will result in greater overhead than the existing method.

Comment: You cannot use condition variables?

Comment: By setting the second parameter to CreateEvent to `true`, you're creating a manual reset event. This is done specifically to allow you to do things like wake up all the threads. If you only want to wake up one thread, set that to `false` so you get an auto-reset event. When you set the event, one thread will wake up, and the event will be reset automatically, so no other threads wake up.

Comment: ... and manual reset events are flawed anyway.  Don't use them, basically.

Comment: @PaulSanders: There is that too--but even they did work, they're not what you want here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a "condition variable" with the "notify one" primitive.

C++ standard library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Win32: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/condition-variables (use the "WakeConditionVariable" function to wake up a single thread)

Comment: If you use condition variables, shouldn't there be a critical section for each thread that will be in a race?

Comment: Correct. But I also saw the comment from Jerry in your question to just use auto-reset events. That would also likely work.

Comment: what mean *likely* ? use SynchronizationEvent event type work without any likely

Comment: @RbMm - Of course, it will work. But you never know what OP might be trying to do. :)

Comment: I checked Jerry's comment.

I'm currently creating a file server and I want to eliminate unnecessary operations related to worker threads.
However, if you change the second value to FALSE in CreateEvent, the following problem occurs.
An event (A) occurs in gqcs and a setevent is performed, but the (A) event does not work properly because all worker theads are actually running.

Comment: @SeongtaekOH - when that happens, the *next* thread to invoke WaitForSingleObject will consume the event and the function will return immediately - a robust design will handle the "spurious wakeup". It's an absolute requirement for conditional variables. But honestly, after I read your question, what you really likely need is a thread pool, not a 10 dedicated threads.  Something to think about.

Comment: Let's consider how to create a thread pool between the main thread and the work threads and wake up the work threads one by one when they are not running.

thank you